# Javascript: how to return a value in a function after an event occurs

Tags: javascript

In javascript, how does one await for an event to occur in a function? I want to create a function, waitUntilFullScreenChange(), which returns false when any of the following events occurs:

```
 document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", function() {
   //return false here});

  /* Firefox */
  document.addEventListener("mozfullscreenchange", function() {
  //return false here});

  /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */

  document.addEventListener("webkitfullscreenchange", function() {
 //return false here});

  /* IE / Edge */
   document.addEventListener("msfullscreenchange", function() {
  //return false here });
```

Is this possible in javascript? I wanted to write a function this way because I need to call a javascript function from a dart file and then parse the result when the event occurs (thus I need to wrap the events in a function and wait for a return value). Thanks for all the help!